# How to get the maxlength of the string a specific RichTextBox control can show on the same line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm using the regular `System.Windows.Form.RichTextBox` control for a WinForm application running on the .NET Framework 2.0 to show a status log. Since the Form and several other child controls, have `AutoSize=True`, the application does not always look the same way on different setups. I have no way to know in advance the exact size of the control and anyway I guess there are some implications related to the ratio (font appearence)/(gui dimensions) of each particular configuration.

So now let's depict the most dynamic scenario. I want to know what's the exact maximum length of the string, a given RichTextBox can show on the same line (without exceeding the border nor word wrapping) where such a RichTextBox is using a generic and known, [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) and size.

In case there's no any straightforward way to accomplish this result, does anyway know if I may use any kind of trick like injecting an incrementally growing test string till some weird event gets fired?

Comment: If you mean the `length` is the count of characters, the answer is `it depends on the Font` and the characters themselves. Your original problem seems to be related to `Scaling`, anyway `Scaling` in `winforms` is something hard to be satisfied, but it at least supports some `automatic scaling`, scaling it manually is not easy, BTW your problem looks like not so serious when you said `the application does not always look the same way`, I think that's what you have to accept, the point is your `GUI` is not broken too much, it just needs to keep usable and accessible.

Comment: yes the length of a string is of course the count of characters. I understand the scaling point you highlighted, anyway I just wanted to eventually further abstract the problem to the extent where you just want to get the information I asked for, at runtime, for a given system. My specific problem was just crafting an header that could fill a whole line on the RichTextBox and keep the title aligned on the center. I solved this problem with the code I posted as an answer to my own question but I'm still curious to know any eventually less overbloated solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I got till now. I used the `TextRenderer` class and the strategy I anticipated on my question above. Of course it makes sense only if the control uses a monospaced font. Despite it works for my problem, I'm still curious to know if anyone knows a better way to reach the same goal. So the question will still be open for a while.

```
int maxStringLength = GetMaxStringLengthPerLine(myRichTextBox);

int GetMaxStringLengthPerLine(RichTextBox textbox) {
   return GetMaxStringLength(textbox.Size.Width, textbox.Font);
}

int GetMaxStringLength(int width, Font font) {
   int i = 0;
   while(TextRenderer.MeasureText(new string('A',++i), font).Width<=width);
   return --i;
}
```

Comment: you should declare some variable to hold the value of `TextRenderer.MeasureText("A",font).Width`, divide `width` by that value, you will get the approximate result which is greater than the actual result. Then your loop would be faster, your `i` will be `decreased` instead.

Comment: Note, using this `TextRenderer` is a little tricky, you should provide the `IDeviceContext` (can be an instance of `Graphics`) as the first argument to get the exact result, it also depends on the `TextFormatFlags` as the last argument. I've tried with some overloads and different arguments, even with certain overload and argument, you don't need any loop, just get the `Width` of 1 char and divide the `width` by that value.

Comment: I realize I have a bit exaggerated just for the sake of explaining the concept :D yes you are right.. it's pointless to loop 1by1 when you already have a really good estimate after few iterations (even just one may be enough as you pointed out). Thanks for your precious and detailed advice.